# Publishing failures into Fusion Tables - Has Oauth 1.0 access token lifetime been reduced?

Tags: oauth, google-fusion-tables

What is the lifetime of an Oauth 1.0 access token when publishing into Fusion Tables?

It appears that it has been very recently (since Jan 2012) reduced to 30 days.

This is breaking the publishing of data from ODK Aggregate into Fusion Tables -- most of our users need long-lived publishing capabilities (e.g., that span the duration of their data collection period).

Answer (score 0):

After further clarification and investigation, I'm glad to report that the token lifetime has not been reduced.

Instead, there are currently a maximum of 25 active tokens allowed for a given site (we use "anonymous") and google account.  If you request a 26th token, the oldest of the existing 25 tokens will be retired.